# Solr not recognising some documents

Tags: indexing, solr

I am relatively new to Solr, and have not found an answer for this issue.

During the indexing process, Solr seems not to recognise certain documents.
I realised this may be because the document/file **name** has certain special characters in it, causing that file to be ignored.

I renamed the files in questions, and re-run the process. This time all the files were succesfully recognised by Solr.
The files in question had '(', ')' and '.' in their names(i.e. brackets and dots).

Is there a set of special characters that Solr does not recognise while loading files?
If so, is there a way to work around this as it may be difficult to rename a large set of documents in the organisation.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you "loading files"? i.e. how are you submitting these files to Solr? What are the exact commands used, which operating system and what shell are you using?

Comment: I am working on a Virtual Machine: Windows Server 2016 Datacentre with a 64 bit O/S. Version of Solr is 7.5. I am using Tika that was installed along with the Solr instance.
I'm using the UI of Solr API for importing i.e. From Core Selector - Data Import - Full Import - Execute
I don't know if this will help, but
- Language for non-unicode programs set to English UK ,
- Server home location is UK

Comment: But how are you submitting these files to Solr? How are you trying to load them?

Comment: So how is your dataimporthandler defined and what is its configuration?

Comment: In the solrconfig.xml file the DataImportHandler class has it's config set to tika-data-config.xml. I have attached part of the tika-data-config.xml in the next comment.

Comment: ...
<entity name="file" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" dataSource="null"
            baseDir="${solr.install.dir}/PDFs" fileName=".*"
            rootEntity="false">
      <field column="file" name="id"/>
      <entity name="pdf" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
              url="${file.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">
        <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
        <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
        <field column="dc:format" name="format" meta="true"/>
        <field column="text" name="text"/>
      </entity>
...
I hope this helps.